# How can ARM processors use more than 4GB of ram?

Tags: raspberry-pi, operating-system, arm, kernel, virtual-memory

I recently started working on my own operating system. I am following jsandler18‘s [awesome tutorial](https://jsandler18.github.io) and making changes as I go to allow it to run on the raspberry pi 4.

Sadly, jsandler18 stopped updating the tutorial before he had finished the page on virtual memory. I read through some other sources, and found a little problem: The ARM l1 address translation table divides the computers RAM into 1-MB blocks. The problem here is that it only allows up to 4096 entries, or 4GB of virtual ram.

Is there some way I can use the ARM MMU to translate more than 4GB of virtual memory?

Comment: the same way a pc or other platform does it.  Just think about pcie it uses a portion of the processors address space as a window into other address spaces.  Same here.  The mmu makes it easier you setup blocks for the applications when an application accesses it it will get a fault if not resident in ram, you swap that ram out (some other applications memory, to media like the hard drive), mark that block so that it faults, and then pull in this applications memory from media and put it in there and complete the access such that the application never knew.

Comment: it is just swap space a subset of the concept of virtual-memory.

Comment: with a 32 bit address space (aarch64 should be larger yes), specifically on traditional ARM linux capable cores and chips, some of that address space is chewed up with peripherals and mmu tables and other things (pcie if any, video as needed, ethernet packet storage, etc).  On a pi the chip design chews up a lot of the ARMs address space leaving but a small window total.  initially 0x20000000 bytes of space later 0x3F000000 bytes of space if I remember right.  Much of it is mapped as cached and mailbox areas.  Half the ram is taken by the GPU by default or at least used to be, etc.

Comment: even when you have a 32 bit x86 pc with 4gb of ram populated you cannot get at 4gb of ram, one gig is used for pcie, some platforms mirror the video memory in there, but then you have swap to take what is left and expand it.  And even 64 bit processors with 4gb of ram initially you could not get at all of it because pcie would take a gig hole out of that address space and in case you were booting a 32 bit operating system the wouldnt move pcie or other stuff above the 4gb mark, would need to set the bios up for that if the bios allowed it.

Comment: today this far after the transition to 64 bit it is more likely to find a bios that will do that possibly by default moving it out of the address space where you are likely to have ram, and open a 2GB hole for pcie in the address space.  In any case you either use a window into a virtual space or you swap, the early 8088/86 days it was a window into a card with more ram, today you simply swap it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tutorial being referenced appears to be executing in ARMV7, which can be thought of as 32-bit ARM. This is roughly equivalent to running in 32-bit PAE mode in X86. Thus using this example it is not possible to to use more that 4GB of virtual memory.

ARMV8 (or AARCH64) supports 64-bit virtual addresses, and would allow mapping more that 4GB of virtual memory.

Switching into ARMV8 is done by switching Exception levels, which are usually denoted as EL0, EL1, EL2 and EL3. The one challenge you could run into is that once you enter AARCH32 mode, you can not go to a lower exception level and switch to AARCH64. For example going from EL1 64-bit -> EL0 32-bit is supported, but going EL1 32-bit -> EL0 64-bit is not. This could pose a challenge if the firmware handing execution off to your OS is in AARCH32 mode.